# Create slide show using post handler

Tags: android

I am Making Andriod app to slide show the image one by one images are inbulit in drawable i am using this code for the app their is no error in it but still my app is not working please help me out I Am Really in need please help me out or their is any other way to do slide show of 100 images one by one then please help and this is the which i have made code

```
public class third extends Activity {
ImageView img ;
Handler handler;
int i;
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.f,R.drawable.g};
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.a);

        for (i = 1; i<drawables.length;)
        {

             handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      img = (ImageView) findViewById(drawables[i]);
                      i++;
                  }
                }, 2000);



        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Simply use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int[] drawables = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.f,R.drawable.g};

    Handler   handler;
    int       i         = 0;
    ImageView img;

    public void slide() {

        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                MainActivity.this.img.setImageResource( MainActivity.this.drawables[MainActivity.this.i] );

                if ( MainActivity.this.i < ( MainActivity.this.drawables.length - 1 ) ) {

                    MainActivity.this.i++;
                } else {
                    MainActivity.this.i = 0;
                }

                Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Next " + MainActivity.this.i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                MainActivity.this.slide();
            }
        }, 3000 );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        this.setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        this.img = ( ImageView ) this.findViewById( R.id.image );

        this.slide();

    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a better way : [android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter](http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/)